# How to edit PayPal API (accept payment)?

Tags: php, forms, paypal, wordpress

I want to edit this PayPal API. I want to add a field name "Tax" under "Item total" and get a 2.5% of total amount and display it on the new field name "Tax"

[image]

Please refer to this (this is what i want) process (just scroll down in the bottom and make a sample payment): http://webcare.com.au/about-us/payment-terms/ then after you submit you'll see the Shipping and handling field name

Comment: Are you using woocommerce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a hidden field of tax_rate in your form and assign % based value in it. In this case 2.5. That should work fine.
There are many such attributes, you can see it [Look here.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)

Comment: <input name="tax_rate" type="hidden" value="2.5" /> the code will be like this?

Comment: Yes. It would be like that